# Mounting /system crashes entire phone

Tags: android, root

I'm running Android 6.0.1 and I'm rooted with SuperSU. I have TWRP recovery.

Any method of writing or allowing wrote access to the /system partition the phone crashes (reboots).

ES file explorer crashes it when mounting /system. 
Terminal crashes it when mounting /system with mount -o remount,rw /system or any variation.

I've tried reflashing SuperSU and found that SuperSU wasn't causing it.

Finally, I can mount it in TWRP just fine. When I boot into system, everything turns back into RO.

Using SuperSu 2.79 systemless root

EDIT:

Im running the ROM that came with my phone which is almost exactly stock. The phone is Blu Life One X2.

Answer (score 0):

The Life One X2 in particular has a feature built into the kernel that forces a reboot anytime the system partition is remounted as RW (Read/Write). So RIP you cant do anything with it.